# preg_match would not execute inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach, preg-match, simple-html-dom

I use simple_html_dom.php to extract links from a certain page.

Link example:

```
sitevision/proxy/platsbanken/svid12_237ec53d11d47b612d78000171/-123388378/Standard/Platsannonser/VisaPlatsannonsSokDetaljerat.aspx;jsessionid=4E02AB2DE23B9E86B1249B2D1C6E5274?q=s%28pf%28fm%2820140601125839%29tm%2820140602125839%29%29%29a%28100%29sp%2814%2C18%29sr%280%2C0%29&ids=5986605&ps=isr%28True%29FI%28-1%29pgi%28400%29
```

When I get all this links I need to get a specific variable from the link.

`preg_match('/29&ids(.*?)&ps=isr(.|$)/is',$href,$addid);`

The preg_match does not result in anything inside

`foreach($html->find('table.tablelist a[shape=rect]') as $e)`

But when I move it outside the foreach statement it works fine.

Could you help me please with this one?

```
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

        $html = file_get_html($actual_link);

        foreach($html->find('table.tablelist a[shape=rect]') as $e)
        {
             $href = $e->href;

             preg_match('/29&ids(.*?)&ps=isr(.|$)/is',$href,$addid); 
             echo $addid = $addid[1];

        }
```

Comment: Please, show more code. It's hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: What do you want to do with: `echo $addid = $addid[1];`?

Comment: Are U sure that U enter the `foreach`?

Comment: Yes, I'm entering for each as I also echo the $href to test it, and I get all of the links.

In the end I need to get ids avue from each link which is 7 digits.

Comment: Consider using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) in combination with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) to retrieve the variable's value from the query string.